# Deserialise a JSON payload that represent a String or an Object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I want to deserialise a JSON payload that represent a field that can be a string (unexpanded) or an object (expanded):

Example payload **unexpanded**: only a string value is sent, that represents contains the id.

```
{
  "id" : "777424881071",
  "category" : "/category/12",
  "title" : "ACADEMY DINOSAUR",
  "description" : "A Epic Drama of ...",
  }
```

Example payload **expanded**: the corresponding id is sent:

```
{
  "id" : "777424881071",
  "category" : {
    "id" : "12",
    "name" : "Children"
  },
  "title" : "ACADEMY DINOSAUR",
  "description" : "A Epic Drama of ...",
  }
```

In java this can be represented with a type like this:

```
public class ExpandableField<T> {
  private String id;
  private T expandedObject;

  public ExpandableField(String id, T expandedObject) {
    this.id = id;
    this.expandedObject = expandedObject;
  }
}
```

See [ExpandableField](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/ExpandableField.java) for a complete example from the stripe java client.

I am wondering how I can write a `JsonDeserializer<ExpandableField<?>>` for Jackson.

```
public class ExpandableFieldDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ExpandableField<?>> {

    @Override
    public ExpandableField<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken token = p.getCurrentToken();
        if (token == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            return new ExpandableField<>(p.getValueAsString(), null);
        }
        else if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            //TODO deserialize object and compute id
            return new ExpandableField<>(id, object);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

My current solution is to load the current tree and to hardcode what corresponding class is with a small method: `private Class<?> computeType(JsonNode node)`.

```
public class ExpandableFieldDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ExpandableField<?>> {

    @Override
    public ExpandableField<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken token = p.getCurrentToken();
        if (token == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            return new ExpandableField<>(p.getValueAsString(), null);
        }
        else if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
            JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);
            String id = null;
            if (node.has("id")) {
                id = node.asText();
            }
            Class<?> typeClass = computeType(node);
            Object object = codec.treeToValue(node, typeClass);
            return new ExpandableField<>(id, object);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Class<?> computeType(JsonNode node) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I would prefer something more dynamic.

---

As comparison, with the **gson** library, the type is accessible in the method signature:

```
deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
```

with `((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0]`, the `context` is capable to deserialize the object with `context.deserialize(json, t)`.

See a complete example here: [ExpandableFieldDeserializer](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/ExpandableFieldDeserializer.java)

---

How can something similar be made with Jackson?

Comment: Are you asking for something similar to "duck typing"? Like asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842029/how-to-do-duck-typing-with-jackson ?

Comment: Also found this: "We wanted our deserializer to automatically instantiate the correct types for us" https://tech.willhaben.at/deserializing-dynamic-json-documents-jackson-objectmapper-on-steroids-9eab587436e2